# How to send values to parent table column in json

Tags: json, spring, rest, api

Customer entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customer")
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long cusId;
    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name="address")
    private String add;


    @Column(name="tel")
    private int tel;


    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="userName")
    private String username;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  mappedBy = "customer")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Complain> complain=new ArrayList<Complain>();
    public Customer() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public Long getCusId() {
        return cusId;
    }
    public void setCusId(Long cusId) {
        this.cusId = cusId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public String getAdd() {
        return add;
    }
    public void setAdd(String add) {
        this.add = add;
    }
    public int getTel() {
        return tel;
    }
    public void setTel(int tel) {
        this.tel = tel;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public List<Complain> getComplain() {
        return complain;
    }
    public void setComplain(List<Complain> complain) {
        this.complain = complain;
    }

}
```

Complain Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Complain")

public class Complain {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="repfirst")
    private String repfirst;

    @Column(name="replast")
    private String replast;


    @Column(name="warranty")
    private String warranty;

    @Column(name="dop")
    private String purDate;

    @Column(name="Nomachine")
    private String Nomachine;

    @Column(name="Complain")
    private String Complain;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
     @JoinColumn(name="cus_id", referencedColumnName = "cusId")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Customer customer;


    public Complain() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRepfirst() {
        return repfirst;
    }

    public void setRepfirst(String repfirst) {
        this.repfirst = repfirst;
    }

    public String getReplast() {
        return replast;
    }

    public void setReplast(String replast) {
        this.replast = replast;
    }

    public String getWarranty() {
        return warranty;
    }

    public void setWarranty(String warranty) {
        this.warranty = warranty;
    }

    public String getPurDate() {
        return purDate;
    }

    public void setPurDate(String purDate) {
        this.purDate = purDate;
    }

    public String getNomachine() {
        return Nomachine;
    }

    public void setNomachine(String nomachine) {
        Nomachine = nomachine;
    }

    public String getComplain() {
        return Complain;
    }

    public void setComplain(String complain) {
        Complain = complain;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    }
```

I want to pass data to the mysql database through the postman tool. How can I pass value for the foreign key column through the json query?

This is the method I have used in controller

```
@PostMapping(path="/",consumes="application/json",produces="application/json")
public void addComplain(@RequestBody Complain complain)
{               


    Integer id = complainService.getAllComplain().size()+1;
    complain.setId(new Long(id));

    complainService.createOrUpdateComplain(complain);   }
```

After I send the request from the postman, all the data are saved except the foreign key. I think I missed something in mapping two tables.

This is my json query

```
{"complain":"No power",
 "repfirst":"hi",
 "replast":"all",
 "warranty":"yes",
 "purDate":"2020-02-29",
 "nomachine":"6",
 "tel":"46544654",
 "Customer":[
             {"cusId":"1"}
            ]
}
```

[Database table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3mCZ.png)

Please help, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
{
 "repfirst": "",
 "replast": "",
 "warranty": "",
 "purDate" : "",
 "Nomachine": "",
 "Complain": "",
 "cus_id": 1
}
```

That should work

```
"Customer":[
             {"cusId":"1"}
            ]
```

This would work if you had `Set<Customer> customers` converted to an array in json, for example.

Comment: I tried both ways that you suggested. But  I had the same problem. CusID column doesn't receive the data.